# Why doesn't my custom login page show with Spring Security 4?

Tags: java, spring-security

I am able to use a custom login page with Spring Security 3.2.4, but after migrating with the code below using 4.0.0, I see a generic login form instead of my custom one:

```
  <beans:bean id="authSuccessHandler" class="com.company.web.RoleBasedAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

  <http disable-url-rewriting="false" use-expressions="true">
    <form-login login-page="/login"
        username-parameter="j_username"
        password-parameter="j_password"
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=true"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler"/>
    <!-- SOME INTERCEPT-URLs (redacted) -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
    <remember-me 
         remember-me-parameter="_spring_security_remember_me"
         remember-me-cookie="SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE"/>
    <logout 
         logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" 
         logout-success-url="/index" />
  </http>
```

I also tried enabling debug logging on the various Spring classes.  I set it on my custom authSuccessHandler, but I don't see any output from it.  No luck with searching on SO or Google either.

Is there anything incompatible about this configuration?

**Update:**

I'm also using Apache Tiles as so:

```
  <definition name="login" extends="scrollableLayout">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/heading_blue.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp"/>
  </definition>
```

And using the following:

```
  <mvc:view-controller path="/login" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring Security 3.x used `spring_security_login` as the default login URL (`source`: [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-form-login-attributes)).  This could be set to a custom value as `<security:form-login login-page="/login">` and mapped to a controller to render a custom page.

Spring Security 4.x has abandoned `spring_security_login` and switched to `login` as the default login URL (`source`: [official Spring Security 4.x migration guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-form-login)).  Therefore, the URL `login` now goes to the default Spring Security infrastructure, that displays the default, auto-generated login page.

The remedy is simple if you are using JSP as the view rendering technology.  Simply rename your login page to `login.jsp`, drop it in the root folder of the page hierarchy and Spring Security will pick it up automatically.  If you are not using JSP, you will have to use a different `login-page` value (perhaps `signin` instead of `login` and then change your controller mapping as well.

Note that the default logout URL has also changed in 4.x.  If you have any custom logic written for the logout URL, do make sure to review that as well.

Do review the official migration guide as a lot of things have changed in 4.x.

Comment: Would that mean that I should remove login-page="/login"?  I tried removing it, but no luck.  I am using Tiles if that makes any difference.  My JSP is called login.jsp.

Comment: Do you have a controller method mapped to `/login` that in turn renders `login.jsp`?

Comment: Yes, it just adds some variables to the model and returns "login."

Comment: In that case, you will have to make the change I have suggested in the answer above - `<security:form-login login-page="login">` will need to be changed to `<security:form-login login-page="signin">` and `@RequestMapping("login")` on the controller will need to change to `@RequestMapping("signin")`.  That should be sufficient.  You can use any value other than the default `login`.

Comment: Interesting - if I remove the controller method, it's still not returning my custom page.  I separately tried your suggested changes and while I do see the custom sign-in page, after attempting a login, it gets stuck on /j_spring_security_check.  I read through the migration guide, but don't see any other configurations that I would need.  Going to leave this open for a bit before giving you the checkmark.

Comment: `j_spring_security_check` is not valid for Spring Security 4.x.  I have gone through the Spring Security 4.x source code and that string does not appear anywhere.  Plus, I successfully migrated my app using the migration guide.  Can you post a sample app with your exact configuration and the problem being replicated somewhere?  That may be an easier route to debug.

Comment: It shows as valid according to the migration guide under section 6.3: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-form-login.  Of course, the source is the best place to look.  I do understand the motivation to move away from the "j_spring" nomenclature.  I will try to post a sample later this week - perhaps in doing so, I will find the error.

Comment: After doing what @manish suggests I also had to add <security:http security="none" pattern="/signin" /> So there is no security on the signin page

Comment: I personally prefer `<security:intercept-url access="permitAll" pattern="/signin"/>`.  It is also possible to use `<security:intercept-url access="isAnonymous()" pattern="/signin"/>`, which would restrict the login page to anonymous users only.  This could create problems if you require users to authenticate for sensitive actions such as placing orders, making payments, password change, etc. even if they are logged in, which is why `permitAll` is better than `isAnonymous()`.

Comment: Using the signin paradigm worked to give me the custom page, so I am marking this as the accepted answer to this question.

Comment: It seems that the auto-generated login page appearing when using `/login` as the login URL [was a bug in 4.0.0](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2919) that has been fixed in 4.0.1.  Do try upgrading to Spring Security 4.0.1 to see if you can use `/login` as the login URL.

Comment: @manish, I renamed my page to login.jsp but am still getting the same issue. am using spring-context version of 4.0.0 while others are 4.0.1, please assist

Comment: @Saurabh, please post a separate question with your configuration and possible a sample app.  Someone should be able to take a look and provide help.  Spring security is quite complicated so it is difficult to help without looking at all the files.  If you cannot share code, try using `/signin` as the URL instead of `/login` as that should work and others have confirmed it as working as well.

Comment: @Manish, please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30838756/spring-security-without-spring-mvc