# Is there a way to disable default "/login" on Spring Security 4.x?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

When Spring Security evolved from version 3.2.x to 4.0.0, multiple modifications became required when using XML based configuration, as stated in the [Migration reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html). After following throught, I'm still struggling with a few issues regarding the new `form-login@login-processing-url` attribute. Even though I have specified it to continue using `/j_spring_security_check` as path, it keeps the new `/login` path active.

I have been using Spring Security along with SpringMVC and began developing with version 3.2.7. I have a Controller mapping the path `/login` to a page that shows the login form and depending on possible parameters received shows a certain error message. Below is my controller

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
                        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout,
                        Model model) {

        if (error != null) {
            model.addAttribute("error", "Usuário e senha inválidos.");
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            model.addAttribute("msg", "Logout bem sucedido.");
        }

        return "login";
    }
}
```

In version 3.2, my `spring-security.xml` file specified the `form-login@login-page` parameter to `/login`, therefore showing my personalized login form (the same path was used for `<logout>`).

Now, even though I have explicitily configured `form-login@login-processing-url`, the `/login` still redirects to spring security's default login page. Besides it, even though I have also specified a `logout@logout-url` attribute, when login out spring still redirects me to the default login-form with the "logout successful" message, instead of my own controller to show my personalized logout message.

When I use the `/login?` path, the application shows my own login form, but if I call `/login?logout` or `/login?error`, which would, respectively, show my logout and error messages, Spring redirects to the default login page.

**Question: *Is there a way to fully disable the `/login` redirection?***

I know I could simply change my personalized path to something else instead, such as `/signin` and avoid the confusion, but I'm doing it as an exercice to understand more about Spring Security 4.x. Besides, I'm concerned an user typing the URL instead of navigating through links would simply drop on spring's default login page.

Additionally, follows an excerpt of my `spring-security.xml` file, already adapted to version 4.x.

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/power/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_POWER_USER')" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login"  <!-- my controller -->
        default-target-url="/" 
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" <!-- to reproduce 3.2 behaviour -->
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" 
            logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
    <headers disabled="true"/>
    <csrf disabled="false"/> <!-- I know it could be ommited -->
</http>
```

**UPDATE (04/16/2015):** Looks like a bug on version 4.0.0. Check my answer.

Comment: I had a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595098/why-doesnt-my-custom-login-page-show-with-spring-security-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my login controller mapping to `/access`. My login not only works (as expected), but for some reason the application stopped returning Spring's default login form when accessing `/login`.

It simply does not recognize the path (404 error). The behaviour I described previously, confusion between default and custom login forms when using `/login` looks to me like a bug. Let's hope gets fixed in future versions.

Therefore, the "fix" I suggest is changing the controller mapping, even though this my reflect in changing the calls on multiple views.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is implement a custom AuthenticationEntryPoint to turn off login redirect (which is set to default).

Here is some starter reading information:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#auth-entry-point

Here is also a example of how it is implemented:

http://krams915.blogspot.com.au/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-integration-using_26.html

Comment: Interesting, but sounds very strange that it became necessary to create a "complex" workaround like that on such a common situation. It's like turning things more complicated on a version upgrade.

Comment: Personally i haven't seen any other methods of doing this, without hacking the Spring Security module. I guess you could create a login page that redirects into a error page for example. Only difference there is that client won't see login page but see error page.