# Spring security without spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to implement spring security without using spring MVC,

below are my snippets

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>cxf</display-name>

       <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/dcd-html/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <init-param>  
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</param-name>  
      <param-value>images</param-value>  
    </init-param>  


    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

        <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

        <filter>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, DELETE</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>



   <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
   </listener>

   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>applicationContext</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>applicationContext</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd 
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail-2.1.xsd">



    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.smart.city.*"></context:component-scan>

    <import resource="/spring/securityContext.xml" />

</beans>
```

Securitycontext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/security

           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">

     <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('PRIV_ADMIN')" />
     <security:http-basic />

     <security:form-login login-page="/login"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="loginFailureHandler"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccessHandler" />
        <!-- <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout.htm" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
            invalidate-session="true"/> -->

</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
     <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceTx">
            <security:password-encoder ref="customPasswordEncoder" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

My problem is if I use `login-page="/login"` I am not getting redirected to my jsp, and if I dont use this attribute, I can see spring's default log in page.

Please assist.

Comment: If you don't use Spring MVC then why do you have a `DispatcherServlet`? If you want to use your JSP then give the path to your JSP not something else. Also with your setup you're loading your whole application twice once with the `ContextLoaderListener` and once with the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: my login.jsp, is placed right under webapp

Comment: Then use `/login.jsp` as the login page url.

Comment: How is your application deployed? As Root?

Comment: Also remove your `DispatcherServlet` as that is destroying normal serving of jsp pages and you stated you aren't using Spring MVC, so remove the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: my application is deployed directly (as root), removed DispatcherServlet still no luck

Comment: Then are you sure it is directly in `src/main/webapp`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80549/discussion-between-saurabh-jhunjhunwala-and-m-deinum).

Comment: yes it is under src/main/webapp

Comment: What isn't happening? What is the result? 404? 500? or??? Check your logs to see what is happening, enable debug logging for Spring Security.

Comment: " The page isn't redirecting properly " - This is the error I see on the browser

Comment: You have protected everything, if you aren't logged in you are redirect to the login page, you are redirect to the login page, you are redirected to the login page... You should allow access to `/login.jsp` for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 things wrong with your configuration:

1. You are redirecting to `/login` for which I highly doubt that there is a mapping.
2. You have protected all URLs hence also your login page, with your current solution you will finish in a redirect loop.

First change your `login-page` property to `/login.jsp` to be redirected to your login page.

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login.jsp"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="loginFailureHandler"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccessHandler" />
```

Secondly permit all access to `/login.jsp` to prevent a redirect loop.

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="permitAll" />
```

Another suggestion, free of charge, you aren't using Spring MVC so you don't need the `DispatcherServlet`, currently it reloads all the beans and you are basically loading your application twice.