# spring security does not redirect to login page

Tags: spring-security

I have a spring-mvc application with spring-security-web:3.2.6. My configuration for the application used to redirect all unauthorized users to login page.
I just tried to upgrade to the spring-security-web:4.0.1 and now I get 500 error instead of login page when I try to access a page

Comment: You'll want to post your XML to try to identify the problem.  Also, you can take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595098/why-doesnt-my-custom-login-page-show-with-spring-security-4

Comment: I am using Java configuration
http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()

Comment: If you get a 500, check the debug log and post the error. You need to provide more information to get an answer.

Comment: In addition to posting the error (as Luke states) ensure you refer to the migration guide http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#m3to4