# Spring migration issue to version 4.x

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have this dispatcher servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">  

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.*,com.mobapp.security.Login.handlers" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" cache-period="31556926"/>    
    <import resource="ConfigFiles/Security.xml"/>
```

security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http>
        <form-login
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />        
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="pwdEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="appUserDetailService" class="com.mobapp.security.AppUserDetailService"></beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="appUserDetailService">
            <password-encoder ref="pwdEncoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>        

</beans:beans>
```

Here is `/login`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error,
        @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    if (error != null) {
        model.addObject("error", "Invalid username and password!");
    }

    if (logout != null) {
        model.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");
    }
    model.setViewName("login");

    return model;

}
```

If i use

```
<spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
```

everything works well

but i use

```
 <spring.version>4.1.7.RELEASE</spring.version>  
 <spring.security.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
```

and try to access `/login` it shows spring default login form instead of my own custome loginf form

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't my custom login page show with Spring Security 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595098/why-doesnt-my-custom-login-page-show-with-spring-security-4)

Answer (score 2):

Spring Security doesn't work the way you are thinking it does! The framework basically provides a filter chain called the DelegatingFilterProxy and embeds it in the ApplicationFilterChain as per the configured (default 100) filter order (a very basic use case, else it's huge :)).

But it is very much configurable! (Thanks to the Dev Team)

Your controller method is not getting executed because the filter chain uses the default login URL as /login in version 4+ (in 3.x it used to be something else, don't remember it anymore ;)). Whenever you try to hit the /login URL it is intercepted by the filter chain and as you are asking for the default login page, it is generated and provided to you (which is the expected behaviour). Your config used to work with 3.x because of this reason only (you trying to hit a URL that was just allowed to be accessed anonymously). In other words, you used to do something (in 3.x) that Spring security can do out of the box; yourself.

In case you wish to use a different URL than the default URL, then you need to explicitly set it in the  element. For example,

```
   <form-login login-page="/custom_login_url"
        default-target-url="/"
        login-processing-url="/auth"
        authentication-failure-url="/custom_login_url?login=failed"
        username-parameter="username_param"
        password-parameter="password_param"
        always-use-default-target="false"/>
```

With this kind of config, you can force Spring security to look for a login URL in the dispatcher context. Your config URL /login may still not hit you custom login action. But you can use the login.jsp (based on your view resolver and controller model view, your login page is login.jsp) as your login page as shown in the example, and Spring security will take care of the rest.

You might want to refer to this  [migration doc from 3.x to 4.x (NS config)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-form-login) for more insight and help.