# unable to display same page with error message in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

the idea is simple If my login fails user will be redirected to `/loginerror` but is not working as excepted

**LoginController**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String login(Model model) {
            return "login";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/loginerror", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String loginFailed(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("error", "true");
            return "login";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String logout(Model model) {
            return "login";
        }
```

**login.jsp**

```
<c:if test="${not empty error}">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <spring:message
                                    code="AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials" />
                                <br />
                            </div>
                        </c:if>
                        <form action="<c:url value= "/j_spring_security_check"></c:url>"
                            method="post">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="User Name"
                                        name='j_username' type="text">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password"
                                        name='j_password' type="password" value="">
                                </div>
                                <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit"
                                    value="Login">
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

**security-context.xml**

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/all/add"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
        default-target-url="/all/add" authentication-failure-url="/loginerror" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    <security:csrf disabled="true" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"
                password="admin" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>

</security:authentication-manager>
```

what I am trying to do is to redirect the user to login page when its login fails but everytime I do I am getting **error 404** page not found on url `localhost......../j_spring_security_check`

**Edit**

**spring error message is** `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials=The user-name or password you entered is incorrect.`

**after putting debug statement inside `/loginerror` method I came to know that this method is not even being invoked**

how to intercept this if url is wrong?

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/security-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: you have the request mapping for "/loginfailed" but not for "/loginerror"

Comment: @guchuan still same error

Comment: Can you post your WEB-INF/web.xml so we can take a look also.

Comment: try something like `authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=true"`.

Comment: @zek I made the edit

Comment: It seems the web.xml is right. How about the annotations above the LoginController class?

Comment: there is only one `@controller` over `LoginController` and rest are on methods

Comment: Have you tried @guchuan's suggestion? Can you also try something this: `authentication-failure-url="/login?error"`

Comment: I'm not sure, but would adding RequestMethod.POST change anything ? Not sure if moving to failure is done by GET...

Comment: the version of spring you are suing does not support <form action="<c:url value= "/j_spring_security_check"></c:url>" method="post"> use login instead as url <form action="<c:url value= "/login"></c:url>" method="post">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the version of spring you are using does not support
`<form action="<c:url value= "/j_spring_security_check"></c:url>" method="post">` 
use /login as url  instead 
`<form action="<c:url value= "/login"></c:url>" method="post">`
since you asked this link clearly explains the differences [Why doesn't my custom login page show with Spring Security 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595098/why-doesnt-my-custom-login-page-show-with-spring-security-4)

Comment: if you can explain why is this working will be great :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a "/loginerror" in your controller, that will be a problem, so of course that method will never get called, either change the failure-url to loginerror loginerr or to loginFailed. As others have pointed out though typically you do -failure-url="/login?error=true" and then use the error request parameter to display to the user they messed up their login.

Comment: thaks for reply I made the edit but its sitll not working

Comment: do you need that default-target-url? I'm looking at my security-context.xml for an app I have done and it doesn't have that.

Comment: dw that is just the url you get redirected to once you login my bad.

Comment: unfortunately everything is leading me to `error 404` not found

Comment: Sorry yeah all looks good. You do have a controller with a mapping for all/add don't you? Otherwise you might need to just look for a working example and go from there.

Comment: yes I have controller and now I have changed security from `/add` to `/` I mean to  home page, not sure why it is not redirecting, In fact I tried some more dummy examples but nothing is proving to be usefull

Answer (score 0):

Check the order of intercept URL , it is based on first in .Maybe that is the problem .
Also try below in your code.

```
always-use-default-target="true"
```

Comment: in `xml` order dosen't matters yeah but I'll like to try that, thanks :)

Comment: Can you try this <http auto-config="true">
  <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" />
  <form-login
      login-page="/login"
      default-target-url="/welcome"
   authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
   username-parameter="username"
   password-parameter="password" />
  <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
  <!-- enable csrf protection -->
  <csrf/>
 </http>